# How to deploy a Safe on Hardhat

Tags: hardhat, gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am developing a Safe Module and would like to use Hardhat to test it. However, I have been so far unable to deploy a Safe using Hardhat. Does anyone have experience doing this? Even when I set my chainId to a chain I know SafeFactory exists for, I experience the error of Invalid Safeproxyfactory Address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run some Safe tests using Hardhat Network in our project. Here is the example: [safe.spec.ts#L212](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/d1058c57367488c8bfd572b8f165c0316231a70d/test/safe/safe.spec.ts#L212)

You have to deploy 3 contracts:

- `GnosisSafeProxyFactory.sol`
- `GnosisSafe.sol`
- `MultiSend.sol`

Then you provide the addresses and the ABIs for Hardhat `chainId` to gnosis SDK

```typescript
import { SafeFactory } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'

// Initialize the Adapter and provide the deployed contract infos

const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({
    ethAdapter,
    contractNetworks: {
        [client.chainId + '']: {
            multiSendAddress: multiSendContract.address,
            multiSendAbi: multiSendAbi,

            safeMasterCopyAddress: safeContract.address,
            safeMasterCopyAbi: safeAbi,

            safeProxyFactoryAbi: proxyFactoryAbi,
            safeProxyFactoryAddress: proxyFactoryContract.address
        }
    }
});
```